# How to delete all rows without deleting the last returned row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to delete all the rows from a `SELECT` without deleting the last returned row by using a trigger when a delete query is executed.

This trigger doesn't work so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_StergereOfertaSpeciala
ON OferteSpeciale
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
DECLARE @nr INTEGER;

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED))
BEGIN
SET @nr = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED); 

DELETE FROM (   
SELECT TOP(@nr - 1)* FROM OferteSpeciale
INNER JOIN DELETED ON OferteSpeciale.codP = Deleted.codP 
    AND OferteSpeciale.codM = Deleted.codM 
    AND OferteSpeciale.dela = Deleted.dela)

END
```

Comment: You do not have an `ORDER BY`, how do you determine the "last row"?

Comment: What does "*the trigger doesn't work*" mean?  What does it do now, or what error does it give?

Comment: Also, ... is `{codp, codM, dela}` a unique or primary key on the `OferteSpeciale` table?

Comment: Yes codP, codM and dela is the unique primary key. The trigger gives a synthax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of getting your concept to work properly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_StergereOfertaSpeciala
ON OferteSpeciale
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @nr INT
    SET @nr = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED)
    IF (@nr > 1) BEGIN
        DELETE o
        FROM OferteSpeciale AS o
            INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP (@nr - 1) * FROM DELETED /* ORDER BY ??? */) AS d
                ON o.codP = d.codP 
                AND o.codM = d.codM 
                AND o.dela = d.dela
    END
END
```

Note the syntax for a delete with a join. Also note that we're arbitrarily choosing the 1 row to keep. I would suggest, as @RBarryYoung has mentioned, specifically ordering the set by *something* to know which row we are keeping.

Another way of doing this which could avoid the somewhat dynamic `TOP` clause (clever, BTW) would be to specifically exclude the record you want to keep using `NOT EXISTS/IN`

Also, you probably want to avoid [trigger recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190946.aspx) and [nested triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx) in this case.

Comment: +1: though actually, you only need to execute the `DELETE` if `@nr` is greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It is exactly what I've needed.